# Я пытаюсь создать одномерный массив типа 'string', а после добавить в него значение переменной, как итог, возникает ошибка

Tags: c#, unity3d

Возможно я не понял саму логику массивов и из-за этого не могу адекватно с ними работать, из-за чего возникают небольшие трудности. Возможно для вас это покажется слишком очевидно, но я ищу решение этой проблемы уже 3 дня.
Воссоздам пример моей попытки добавления переменной в массив:

```
public double[] PriceList; // массив параметры которого я задаю в Unity
public string[] resultMoney; // массив параметры которого я пытаюсь задать в коде
void Update()
    {
        string resultMoney[0] = { string.Format("{0:f1}", Money) }; // редактирую формат отображения float числа

        MoneyText.text = resultMoney[0] + "$"; // попытка присвоения массива с индексом 0 - тексту
    }
```

Как итог, Unity не даёт запустить данное приложение (ошибок тоже не выдаёт). Если я сделаю подобное с переменной, то это сработает.

Comment: Юнити не может не выдавать ошибок. Потому что `string resultMoney[0]` - уже ошибка. Без `string` вроде должно заработать

Comment: К сожалению это не сработало, выдаёт ошибку CS0746 (Invalid anonymous type member declarator.) Я пытался исправить эту ошибку документацией от Microsoft, но не совсем понимаю как это можно применить к массиву.
Вот ссылка на решение этой проблемы: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0746

Comment: а вот так `resultMoney[0] = string.Format("{0:f1}", Money);`  что будет?

Comment: кстати, где в коде Money?

Comment: Да, в примере кода я забыл добавить эту переменную. Ваш второй способ сработал, игра теперь запускается но после запуска выдаёт ошибку "IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
(wrapper stelemref) System.Object.virt_stelemref_sealed_class(intptr,object)
Game.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Game.cs:61)". Думаю это не проблема, сейчас подкорректирую и всё сработает.
Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

Если хочется на ходу добавлять элементы - для этого существует вместо массива `List<String>`. Массивы же созданы для статического неизменного количества элементов.

---

Судя по коду из вопроса `resultMoney` не инициализирован в принципе. Его как такового в памяти вообще не существует.

А ты на каждом кадре обращаешся к нулевому элементу несуществующего массива и пытаешься в него записать значение.

Даже более того, ты обращаешся не к глобальному `resultMoney`, а пытаешься создавать локальный

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена, нужно было изменить вариант присвоения переменной к массиву.

Из:

```
public string[] resultMoney;
// ...
string resultMoney[0] = { string.Format("{0:f1}", Money) };
```

На:

```
public string[] resultMoney;
// ...
resultMoney[0] = string.Format("{0:f1}", Money);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что ты используешь массив не инициализируя его.

`string[] m = new string[3]; //если массив имеет 3 элемента.`